# Obtaining mean of dataframe by value groups in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

Once again I consult your wisdom.

I have 2 dataframes of the form:

```
**data1sample**
ID     value
water  3
water  5
fire   1
fire   3
fire   2
air    1

**data2controls**
ID     value
water  1
fire   3
air    5
```

I want to use the values in my control dataframe (data2controls) and know their corresponding percentile in the sample distribution (data1sample). I have to classify each sample by their ID (meaning, get fire control against fire sample, and water against water, etc), but I haven't been able to do so.

I am using the command:

```
mean(data1sample[data1sample$ID == data2controls$ID,] <= data2controls$value)
```

but I get the error

```
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors
```

What I am after is basically the percentile of the value in dataframe2 calculated based on the samples of dataframe1 (I am trying to obtain the percentile as in percentile = mean(data1sample$value(by ID) <= dataframe2$value))

So something like this:

```
**data2controls**
ID     value  percentile(based on data1 sample values)
water  1      .30
fire   3      .14
air    5      .1
```

Please disregard the percentile values, they're just made up to show desired output.

I'd love if someone could give me a hand! Thanks!!

Comment: What is your desired output please

Comment: Your command doesn't work because ID is a factor. Convert to character with as.character() and you won't get an error. As to whether it returns what you want, we don't know without you answering David's comment.

Comment: "Percentile" and "mean" are not interchangeable terms. If you provide desired output, we might understand which you are really seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer without the desired output, but I will try to guess it here:

```
library(dplyr)

data1sample <- data.frame(ID = c("water", "water", "fire", "fire", "fire", "air"), value = c(3,5,1,3,2,1))

data2sample <- data.frame(ID = c("water", "fire", "air"), value = c(1,3,5))

by_ID <- data1sample %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(control = mean(value))

data2sample %>% inner_join(by_ID)
#> Joining, by = "ID"
#>      ID value control
#> 1 water     1       4
#> 2  fire     3       2
#> 3   air     5       1
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the result I think you're after?

```
for(i in d2$ID){

     x <- mean(d1[d1$ID == i & d1$value <= d2[d2$ID == i, 'value'], 'value'])
     print(x)
}
```

Based on the data you provided it returns NaN for water because there are no 'water's that meet your criterion, and so div by 0